# "To" or "that" after passive construction?

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, to-infinitive

When I study, I saw sentence like this:

> Earthquake rupture ***has been thought*** to happen by enlargement of a crack.

There is a information for this sentence in my book and by the way "has been thought" was gap and it was the answer of book. The information briefly is:

> Since there are no adverbs of time and the "to" that comes after the gap is taken into account, the Present Perfect Tense must be chosen.

Questions are:

1. So, through this information, will I must to choose "Present Perfect Tense" when I see "to"?
2. What if I say "that" instead of "to"? Would it be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's the sentence your book provides?

Comment: Yes I'm definitely sure.

Comment: Is the sentence from a headline?

Comment: If it is from a headline, then that would explain the omission of articles.